# Using own keystore in java code

Tags: java, tomcat, keystore, keytool, private-key

I want to **use keystore to save a private key**. I use this private key to encrypt datasource password.
I generated **myfile.keystore** file with **keytool** and added the following configuration in Tomact server.xml file.

```
<Connector
protocol="HTTP/1.1"
port="8443" maxThreads="200"
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="myfile.keystore" keystorePass="password"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

**How can I read this private key to use in Java code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit of XML configuration you sent us is only to configure the SSL for the tomcat server. It has nothing to do with the storage / reading of a private key for another purpose.

Here is a bit of code to load and initialize the key store.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("myfile.keystore");

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
Key key = keystore.getKey("my-alias", "password".toCharArray());
```

HIH

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was asking about :)